# how to configure and use karma to work with requirejs for nodejs unit testing using mocha and chai?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, requirejs, karma-runner

I have spent lots of days and days to make this karma working with requirejs for nodejs unit testing using mocha and chai. for nodejs unit testing karma config is not required but i want browser to display. your any response is appreciated. it seems i have to specify each single dependent JS library in test-main.how can it load all js from node_modules before start of unit test

```
 testservice
    |   |
    |    ---- node_modules
    |   
    |   |  
    |    -----service 
    |     |-----demo.js
    |
    |    |--util
    |         |
    |         --httputil.js
    |   
    |    |
    |    ---- test
    |           |  
    |        ---- directtest    
    |               |
    |               ---- demo_Test.js 
    |                
    |
    |    |
    |    ---- test-main     
    |           |
    |            ---- test-main.js
    |           -----mocha.opts
    |
    |    |
    |     ---- karma.conf.js 
    |    
    |    | 
    |    ---- AppRoute.js
    |    -----server.js    
    |
    |    |   
    |    ------package.json
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs'],
    files: [

        { pattern: 'node_modules/**/*.js', included: false },  
        { pattern: 'node_modules/**/*/*.js', included: false },
        'test/test-main/test-main.js',
        { pattern: 'test/test-main/*.js', included: false },
        { pattern: 'service/*.js', included: false },
        { pattern: 'util/*.js', included: false },
        { pattern: 'test/directtest/*.js', included: false }

    ],
    exclude: [

    ],

    reporters: ['progress','html'],

    htmlReporter: {
      outputFile: 'test/report/units.html',
      pageTitle: 'test Tests',
      subPageTitle: 'A sample project description'
    },  

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

test-main.js

```
(function() {

  var specFiles = null;
  var baseUrl = '';
  var requirejsCallback = null;
  if (typeof window != 'undefined' && window.__karma__ != undefined) {

    baseUrl = '/base';
    requirejsCallback = window.__karma__.start;
    specFiles = [];
    for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
      if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
          if (/.*\/directtest\/*\/.+_Test\.js$/.test(file)) {
          specFiles.push(file);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  requirejs.config({

      baseUrl: baseUrl,

      paths: {
          'nodemodule': './node_modules/*/*',
        'chai': './node_modules/chai/chai',
        'sinon': './node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon',
        'chaiHttp': './node_modules/chai-http/dist/chai-http',
        'util':'./util/httputil',
        'demotest':'./service/demo'
      },

      deps: specFiles,
      callback: requirejsCallback
  });
})();
```

demo_Test.js

```
define(['chai', 'sinon', 'chaiHttp', 'util','demotest'], function (chai, sinon, chaiHttp,util,demotest) {
 //define(function (require, exports, module) { --tried this way but still    getting error
  describe("should work", function () { 
    //using this block of code to get all js from node_module but seems not doing as of my intention.  
    var Other;
      var testService= require("../../service/demo");
    var expect = require('chai').expect;   

     beforeEach(function(done){
        requirejs(['./node_modules/*/*'], function(_File){
            Other = _File;
            done(); 
        });
    });

    it('should work', function () {
        expect(true).to.be.true;
    });

     it('test', function () {
          expect(testService.callSomeFunc({ "xxx": "1" }, {})).to.be.equal("x1");
      });

    });

});
demo.js


       var httpUtil = require('../util/httputil_test'); // is calling diff
                                                             JS(httputil.js)
         exports.function = abc(){ ....}// i want to write testcase for abc()
    httputil.js


        var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client; 
              var restClient = new Client();
        // node-rest-client third party lib if i specify this module again complains for other negotiator library not loaded so and so. i want all depency to be automatically resolved and get from node_modules itself. 

    i tried also change in karma.conf.js with this option
      { pattern: 'node_modules/**/*.js', included: true  },  
      { pattern: 'node_modules/**/*/*.js', included: true }
 but no luck
```

ERROR:

```
08 05 2016 05:55:56.170:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Work/New folder/working/testservice/node_modules/chai/chai.js
08 05 2016 05:55:56.189:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Work/New folder/working/testservice/node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js
08 05 2016 05:55:56.224:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Work/New folder/working/testservice/node_modules/chai-http/dist/chai-http.js
08 05 2016 05:55:56.265:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Work/New folder/working/testservice/util/HttpUtil.js
08 05 2016 05:55:56.316:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Work/New folder/working/testservice/service/demo.js
Chrome 50.0.2661 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Module name "node-rest-client" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at C:/Work/New folder/working/testservice/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:140
```